# Cannot add image through Magento Cms wysiwyg editor

Tags: magento, wysiwyg

When i tried to add a image through wysiwyg editor and tried to save the page it took too long to respond i got the following error

```
a:5:{i:0;s:25:"Unsupported image format.";i:1;s:1001:"#0 /var/www/html/project1/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php(51): Varien_Image_Adapter_Gd2->_getCallback('create')
#1 /var/www/html/project1/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/WysiwygController.php(52): Varien_Image_Adapter_Gd2->open('http://121.0.0....')
#2 /var/www/html/project1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Adminhtml_Cms_WysiwygController->directiveAction()
#3 /var/www/html/project1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('directive')
#4 /var/www/html/project1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#5 /var/www/html/project1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#6 /var/www/html/project1/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /var/www/html/project1/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:150:"/index.php/admin/cms_wysiwyg/directive/___directive/e3ttZWRpYSB1cmw9Ind5c2l3eWcvcmd0LXNsaWRlci1pbWcwMS5qcGcifX0,/key/ceed8184f5f336aafcc307f8623aff45/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Even though the page gets saved i cant view the image in CMS editor

Comment: I would think the clue is in the error message 'Unsupported image format'.  Have you tried a different image format?

Comment: Yes.The problem is not with the image since the image when uploaded in the test version worked fine

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that Magento is generating a dynamic link with admin path in it. See line 8 in your error : `/index.php/admin/cms_wysiwyg/directive/___directive/e3ttZWRpYSB1cmw9Ind5c2l3eWcvcmd0LXNsaWRlci1pbWcwMS5qcGcifX0,/key/ceed8184f5f336aafcc307f8623aff45/` - this is the link to your image, which is generated by the WYSIWYG.

As this link has no known image extension in the end, I assume, the error you got is produced.

**The solution is to change just one setting in admin :**

`System -> Configuration -> General -> Content Management -> Use Static URLs for Media Content in WYSIWYG for Catalog` to `Yes`

*I found that this setting is checked in `/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/WYSIWYG/Images.php` on line 180 ( in Magento 1.7.0.2 ) and depending on that either static or dynamic links are generated.*

Comment: I have also gone with this solution for now, but it seems that this greatly limits portability of the Magento installation, as the warning next to this field says: `Any media content will be inserted into editor as a static URL. It is not updated if the system configuration base URL changes.`. So if somebody comes up with a better solution, please post it!

Answer (score 2):

It's a Magento bug lack of consideration with specific store view.

Rewrite method `getImageHtmlDeclaration()` of `Mage_Cms_Helper_Wysiwyg_Images`, to modify source code:

```
$mediaPath = str_replace(Mage::getBaseUrl('media'), '', $fileurl);
```

*to*

```
$mediaPath = str_replace(Mage::app()->getStore($this->_storeId)->getBaseUrl('media'), '', $fileurl);
```

Comment: this might do the trick for me, is there any other tweak related to this that I need to hunt down?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if allow_url_fopen was enabled on this server? Today I encountered the same exact problem, and changing this fixed the issue.

There are several ways to change this:

- php.ini
- apache configuration
- vhost config
- .htaccess file

You'll have to choose the best way that fits your webserver setup.

I fixed mine by changing my Apache VirtualHost configuration file to fix it:

```
php_admin_value allow_url_fopen on
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception happens when editing a cms page that contains images from the skin folder. Because when we use custom admin theme, placeholder image is not available in adminhtml TinyMCE.

Fix: Copy placeholder image from adminhtml/default/default/ to custom theme and it will stop exceptions like this.

```
/skin/adminhtml/default/THEME/images/wysiwyg/skin_image.png
```

[image: skin images placeholder for TinyMCE]

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problem.
The solution was to create folder /media/wysiwyg

Answer (score -1):

Refresh your magento cache and flush everything